# Working with Generic Types in Java(comparing and sum using the same type)

Tags: java, generics, upperbound

I have been researching towards the answer to a tricky question in my first year java course, specifically i need to make a program capable of both summing the elements in a generic list, and finding the highest and lowest in the list.

I am perfectly capable of completing both of these tasks individually, having T(the generic type) extend Number for summing, and Comparable for comparing. The problem occurs when I attempt to accomplish both of the tasks on the same generic type seeing as java is incapable of multiple inheritance.

In short, how could I accomplish both of these tasks while having the upper bound of T be the Number class?

Code snippets and advice are appreciated!

Comment: http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/javaian5_chap04/index1.html looks like it may help you.

Answer (score 5):

`T extends Number & Comparable<T>` should do it. `T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>` is a bit more general.

Java does support "multiple inheritance of interface" (and perhaps some weirdo multiple inheritance of implementation" in Java SE 8). A class extends one other class and can implement many interface.

(Not sure if `java.lang.Number` is what you want for summation. You might want to introduce you own type along similar lines to `Comparator`.)

Comment: Thanks ever so much with that! Since we haven't worked with comparator at all, i will simply use the fact that the elements must all be Number(s)  and take their doubleValue(); My prof isn't exactly the greatest at providing such info to us, so again thanks!